# Python 3 Largest product of an 1000 digit number using 12 consecutive number...?

Tags: python

There is a 1000-digit number, below. If you multiply five consecutive digits, the largest value you can find is 9 × 5 × 9 × 9 × 9 = 32805. Multiplying 12 consecutive digits, what is the largest product you can find?

Does anyone have ANY idea how to solve this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with Python?  And where is your code?

Comment: Is this a maths problem or a programming problem, I wonder.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: I don't have a code because I am unsure how to approach the problem using python. Any ideas?

Comment: Would it be helpful to know that `map(int, str(1234))` will give you  `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't python, but it also isn't hard, so I will give it a shot. Since the group of 5 numbers with the highest product is 95999, then your 12 digits will be combinations of that. The highest product possible without going above 32805 for 5 digits is 959999599995, which has a product of 48427561125.